# Make two tables side by side not overlap as screen gets smaller

Tags: html, css

Is there an easy way to get table 1 to not get overlapped by table 2 as the screen gets smaller.

Here is how my tables are currently formatted:

```
   <div style="width: 100%;">
     <div style="width: 15%; float: left;">
     <table class="display table table-responsive" id="smart_table" width="100%">
    </table> </div>
     <div style="width: 85%; float: left;">
    <table id="example" class="display table-responsive" width="100%">
    </table></div></div>
```

EDIT: As my advanced theory was too broad of a question, this can be deleted (it will not let me). Thanks

Comment: They ***don't*** overlap. You've set the first one to `15%` of the entire available width. Even when its contents don't fit inside that space. So its contents overflow it. But it, the table, is exactly `15%`. To avoid it becoming too narrow, provide a `min-width`. Alternatively, you can give both tables a width of `100%` under a certain viewport width (use `@media` queries).

Comment: If you want genuinely responsive tables to match your "advanced theory" (especially when considering cross-browser caveats) it takes more considerations and this becomes an overly broad question sorry.

Comment: Not having an easy answer for the advanced theory is actually the "answer" I needed. Using bootstrap seems to work ok. And using @media queries also helps. Putting a min-width on table1 helped to as Andrei said.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```
  <div style="display: flex">
     <div style="flex: 1; overflow: auto;">
       <table class="display table table-responsive" id="smart_table" width="100%">
       </table> 
     </div>
     <div style="flex: 4; overflow: auto;">
       <table id="example" class="display table-responsive" width="100%">
       </table>
     </div>
   </div>
```

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/jjsalgado/pen/JxyqGB)

Comment: This is behaving ***exactly*** as what he has now, except you're not showing the content (which ***will*** overflow when placed).

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting his question right, but [it looks fine for me](https://media.giphy.com/media/9tZhEzsBE0Dorc1ZfC/giphy.gif)

Comment: @suppko, what you've done there would behave the same with what OP has. OP's problem is that when you're narrowing the first table's container below a certain width, the content overflows. And this solution doesn't fix that problem in the least. From this point of view, this answer is just a more modern way of achieving exactly what OP has (two floating divs with the sum of widths equaling `100%`). The main difference is that in the classic solution the parent needs `overflow:hidden` to expand its background beneath the children.

Answer (score 0):

Set the table wrapping divs (columns?) to have `display:inline-block`
and change the width attributes of the tables so that they fit next to each other.

Comment: How is setting a floating div's display to `inline-block` going to help? Have you tested your answer before posting?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu the answer was tested on the demo OP has provided, and it works. divs have by default their display set to block, which in turn will cause them to be stacked vertically, by setting them to inline-block you are allowing them to stack horizontally.
Have you used CSS before commenting?

Comment: Have you noticed they stack horizontally in OP's example without `display:inline-block`? I wonder what this `float:left` does...

Comment: what it does is break the design on smaller resolutions, it's one of the reasons he's getting into that problem.

Comment: "*Break the design"* doesn't really mean anything. I already explained it under the question. Technically, the table containers do not overlap. The first one's content overflows on narrow screens. Applying `display:inline-block` to it won't prevent `overflow`. Considering the element already has `float:left`, `display:inline-block` does exactly ***nothing***.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a overflow property to your main container to prevent the two divs from overlapping.

```
<div style="width: 100%;overflow: hidden;">
```

However, your second table will be pushed below your first one.